# Why does mypy error if I assign only one of two generic typevars in a classmethod?

Tags: python, generics, mypy

(python 3.10.6, mypy 0.990)

The following examples are all accepted by mypy:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
class Maybe(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, val: T):
        self._val = val
    
    @classmethod
    def empty(cls):
        return cls(None)
```

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

U = TypeVar('U')
V = TypeVar('V')
class Example(Generic[U, V]):
    def __init__(self, a: U, b: V):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
    
    @classmethod
    def empty(cls):
        return cls(None, None)
```

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

U = TypeVar('U')
V = TypeVar('V')
class Example(Generic[U, V]):
    def __init__(self, a: U, b: V):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @classmethod
    def both(cls, val: U, b: V):
        return cls(val, b)
```

But this case returns the following error: `error: Argument 2 to "Example" has incompatible type "None"; expected "V"  [arg-type]`

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

U = TypeVar('U')
V = TypeVar('V')
class Example(Generic[U, V]):
    def __init__(self, a: U, b: V):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @classmethod
    def first(cls, val: U):
        return cls(val, None)
```

It seems that mypy accepts binding generic inputs to typevars, accepts binding concrete values to infer typevars, but doesn't permit a mix of binding and inferring typevars. What's going on?

Comment: Opened https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14078

Comment: Perhaps it is worth noting that Pyright does not report any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** what if I call `type(Example(0, 0)).first(0)`? We can't infer `cls` as `type[Example[int, None]]` in that case.

##### A rambling explanation

It's typically not type-safe to call a class in Python. The first two examples actually allow type errors because I can subclass them and change the `__init__`. This type checks but fails at runtime:

```
class Maybe1(Maybe[int]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(0)

Maybe1.empty()
```

OK, so what if we make `Maybe` `@final`? Then `Maybe1` can't be defined and the problem goes away. Or does it? We'll come back to this.

Regarding `Example`, it's not safe to call `cls` if it's typed as the enclosing class. So we can either call `Example`

```
class Example(Generic[U, V]):
    def __init__(self, a: U, b: V):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @classmethod
    def first(cls, val: U) -> Example[U, None]:
        return Example(val, None)
```

or type `cls` as a function

```
class Example(Generic[U, V]):
    def __init__(self, a: U, b: V):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @classmethod
    def first(
        cls: Callable[[U, None], Example[U, None]],
        val: U
    ) -> Example[U, None]:
        return cls(val, None)
```

Obviously neither of these will work if you want a subclass's `Example1.first` to produce an `Example1`. I think Python's lack of HKTs prohibits typing that properly. It may look something like

```
# not valid Python

E = TypeVar("E", bound=Example)

class Example(Generic[U, V]):
    def __init__(self, a: U, b: V):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @classmethod
    def first(cls: Callable[[U, None], E[U, None]], val: U) -> E[U, None]:
        return cls(val, None)
```

I [don't believe](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-generic-classes) `Self` in Python 3.11 helps here

> we reject using Self with type arguments

We mentioned `@final`, so what if we `@final` `Example`?

```
@final
class Example(Generic[U, V]):
    def __init__(self, a: U, b: V):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @classmethod
    def first(cls, val: U) -> Example[U, None]:
        return cls(val, None)
```

Here's where we recover your error. It's reasonable to ask Python to infer `Example` in `Example.first(0)` to be `Example[int, None]`, but what if we do `type(Example(0, 0)).first(0)`? Then we can't infer `type(Example(0, 0))` as `Example[int, None]`, so we can't infer as `Example[int, None]` in all cases.